# Combinations problem sanity check

Tags: combinatorics

> $8$ criminals are lined in a row. The police officer has to shoot $3$ of them in such a way that no two consecutive criminals get shot. In how many ways can this be done?

P.S. - terrible way to frame a question I agree

I counted all the ways he could choose $3$ criminals from $8$ i.e.$\binom83$

Then I thought of ways in which he could choose two consecutive criminals, which is namely $7$ from the following set ${({a,(a+1) | 1≤a≤7)}}$

And I thought that the cases of consecutive occurrence if subtracted from the total should give me the answer owing to complimentary principle, if you would. But it turns out, the answer does not match with the solution given.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You'll need to be careful with the case that it was three consecutive criminals who were the ones shot.  If you were counting how many ways two consecutive criminals were shot, `XX` denoting a pair of shot criminals, `x` denoting a single shot criminal, and `o` denoting a criminal who wasn't shot, you'll need to pay attention to how `XXxooooo` and `xXXooooo` might have been counted differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask where you went wrong.  It isn't a bad idea what you had, though inefficient.  As alluded to in my comment above, you seem to have missed handling the count correctly as it pertains to the special case of three shot prisoners in a row.  `XXxooooo` and `xXXooooo` might have been counted separately.

---

For a much easier approach, consider a different problem.

Consider the number of prisoners who were not shot to the left of the left-most prisoner who was.  Then consider the number of prisoners who were not shot between the first prisoner who was and the next prisoner who was.  Continue in this manner.

Label those numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$

Recognize that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=5$

Recognize that to ensure no adjacent prisoners were shot, that this implies $x_2\geq 1$ and $x_3\geq 1$.  Otherwise, $x_1\geq 0$ and $x_4\geq 0$.

This leads us to finding the number of integer solutions to the system:

$$\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=5\\x_1\geq 0\\x_2\geq 1\\x_3\geq 1\\x_4\geq 0\end{cases}$$

This becomes a standard stars-and-bars question.

> $\binom{3+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{6}{3}=20$